# Laravel 5.6 show database records older than current date and time

Tags: mysql, datetime, query-builder, laravel-5.6

I need to get the data from my database where only the data older than today should be shown. this is the code i am using

```
$curdate=Carbon::now();
    $papers = DB::table('papers')
    ->join('payments','papers.id','=','payments.paper_id')
    ->join('tutors','papers.tutor_id','tutors.id')
    ->select('papers.*','tutors.name',DB::Raw('TIMEDIFF(papers.release_date,papers.live_end_time)AS diff'))
    ->where('papers.release_date',null)
    ->orWhere('papers.live_end_time', '>=' ,$curdate)
    ->where('papers.id','=','payments.paper_id')
    ->where('payments.user_id',$id)
    ->get();
```

This gives my the data where `release_date` is null but doesn't give me the data when the `live_end_time` is set to a future date. Is there a different method to complete this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem I had to change the default timezone in `config/app.php`

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'Asia/Colombo',
```

`timezone` should be changed according to your region.